# Not able to Insert record into two table using spring jdbc template and declarative transaction appraoch

Tags: java, mysql, spring-jdbc

I have trying to insert record into different table using spring `jdbc` template and transaction approach but not able to do that.

The code looks like this:

```
@Transactional
    public void insertIntoTwoTables(){  




        final KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

        insertRole(keyHolder);
        final String person = "insert into person (first_name, last_name, description, role_id) values ('?,?,?,?)";
        keyHolder.getKey().longValue();
        jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {

            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con)
                    throws SQLException {
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(person);
                ps.setObject(1, "sahil");
                ps.setObject(2, "Goyal");
                ps.setObject(3, "This is again test");
                ps.setObject(4, keyHolder.getKey().longValue());
                return ps;
            }
        });
    }

    private KeyHolder insertRole(KeyHolder keyHolder){
        final String role = "insert into role (name, code) values (?,?)";
        jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {

            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con)
                    throws SQLException {
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(role, new String[]{"id"});
                ps.setObject(1, "Manager");
                ps.setObject(2, "MANAGER");
                return ps;
            }
        }, keyHolder);

        return keyHolder;
    }
```

When I run this code it runs perfectly fine but does not insert anything into data base.
This problem happen when I run it using @Transactional annotation. If I delete then it works fine. So, I this task can be done in transactional environment.

Config file looks like this

```
<bean id="bDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="postgres" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test" />
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

I test the code in both cases

but it does not inser anything into database.

Comment: Is the autocommit enabled for your connection?

Comment: but one thing that i noticed keyholder always return the new id even though it is not insert into role table.